# What is System-Wide Processing?

Tags: development-process, qa-architect

I am not sure if I should post this question here, but I did not found any other stackexchange site which might be more helpful.

If this question is better to be asked somewhere else, please feel free to move it at the appropriate stackexchange site.

Basically, I am writing an Architecture design document for a specific Software engineering project of my university, and I have to also complete a "System-Wide Processing" section at the report. However I have no idea what this is.

Could anyone help me understand what is this, and give some examples just for me to understand better?

Thanks a lot

John

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about testing/QA.

Comment: Is the "System-Wide Processing" section part of a sample or template document? If so, where did you get the document? That seems the place to start. Or with whoever has assigned you this task.

Answer (score 0):

The system wide approach has been developed for application to statistical capacity building in order to facilitate the scaling up of government and donor support for statistics. The approach draws heavily on lessons learn from the Sector Wide Approaches (SWAps) used successfully in areas such as health, education and agriculture.
It is a thematic application of that approach directed towards supporting a locally owned and led programme to develop the National Statistical System in a comprehensive and co-ordinate way, moving towards use of country systems and procedures for implementation.
The process of preparing a statistical strategy, covering the whole, or at least the main parts, of a national statistical system, provides a framework within which a system wide approach (also called a programme based approach) can be used to deliver co-ordinates and harmonized financial and technical assistance.